# How to change the build system for one of my node module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, uglifyjs

I am trying to use Yjs with React. Everything works perfectly except it cannot `npm run build`. The error it is giving me is that `static/js/main.499b0481.js from UglifyJs` and `SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (requireModule) [./~/yjs/src/y.js:66,0]`. So here is the problem, what is inside y.js line 66 is `let requireModule = {}` which is an expression Uglify can't parse. I wonder how can I specify that for this node module, I want to build it with Babel instead of Uglify. Actually I couldn't find what caused it to be built using Uglify. I tried to add `include: [/node_modules\/yjs/],` to my webpack.config but it didn't change anything. Any good ideas?

I actually found this code inside their npm package

```js
gulp.task('dist:es6', function () {
    return (browserify({
      entries: files.dist,
      debug: true,
      standalone: options.moduleName
    }).bundle()
      .pipe(source(options.targetName))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe($.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
      // .pipe($.uglify()) -- generators not yet supported see #448
      .pipe($.rename({
        extname: '.es6'
      }))
      .pipe(header(banner, { pkg: require('./package.json') }))
      .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/')))
  })
```

But somehow it had zero effect in the build process

Comment: Any reason you can't just run all of your files through Babel first then Uglify?

Comment: I actually tried to take out 'exclude: /node_modules/,' from my webpack config, but somehow nothing changed.

Comment: In their node module package, I even saw they took out .pip(uglify()) if it is es6, but I don't know why it was still uglifying.